# Unity: How to transform camera view as a different shape?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, unityscript

Normal camera is rectangle view, but I wanna trapezoid shape as camera view

How to change it with script? It is not cropping.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you can't transform CAMERA in this way, but you can render to texture and then attach it to trapezoid plane.

Or without cropping u can rotate camera. I do not think that playing with matrices in unity - a good idea